# How to disable (window).scroll function after loading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi i have a slider which will slide from side if i scroll down certain amount in browser and it will slide back if i scroll up. Also i have a close function it will close the slide once i click.

I used `(window).scroll` to measure the scroll amount based on this i have given a condition to make the slide happen.

Now the problem is if I am at the bottom of the window when i click "close" it closes the slide but after that when I scroll up the slide again coming this is because the scroll amount condition which i given to slide.

So i went to store a cookie when a click function triggered. By checking the cookie value i let the slide function to happen.

Cookies are created once i click the close then also the same problem happening but when i reload page the slide function is not happening.

Is this Because of `(window).scroll` function priority or Something?
Do anybody know on what problem am I struggling?

Comment: please show some code or link to a jsfiddle, and ideally also rephrase your post because it is nearly impossible to figure out what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if I do understand you correctly.

Why don't you just set the overflow css property of the element to hidden when the trigger calls?
Isn't that your problem?